# Postgresql wont accept remote connections

Tags: postgresql, centos, psql, pgadmin

I tried opening ports in IP Tables,,
Set Listen address to '*'
Added
**host all all 23.81.27.0/24 trust**
and
**host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust**

YouGetSignal shows the port is closed, and i can't connect to my DB via PgAdmin.

I get

> could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
>   Is the server running on host "23.81.27.206" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

I already tried to reboot Postgresql, IPtables, and the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding (or uncommenting) "listen *" in postgresql.conf
then restart postgresql.

Comment: It is uncommented; Show Listen_address; shows STAR. YougetSignal can't see port 5432 as open.